# Given a set of $(x,y)$ coordinates find a given $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, nonlinear-optimization

I have a set of $(x,y)$ coordinates:
$(0,975), (500,2698), (2000,7238),\dots, (5000,17476),(5500,19221)$

I'm trying to find the most accurate way to find $y$ for a given $x$.

Tentative one:
I've tried linear regression (and polynomial) but neither gives me back the exact same $y$ I had for $x$ that I gave to the model (to solve my problem, it's actually needed that I find them back)

Tentative two:
For a given $x$, find the corresponding two coordinates between the point - then compute the linear equation between those two points, and then find your $y$.

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: There are two different procedures: approximation and interpolation. First does not save given points (x,y), second -- does save. In the case when polynomial degree is equal to $n-1$, where $n$ is number of points, best polynomial approximation is also interpolation.

Comment: Tentative 3 : cubic splines.

Comment: Tentative 2 is called piecewise linear approximation, which is a subset of spline approximation (see Tentative 3 above).